# Allocating tasks to parallel workers so that expected cost is roughly equal

Tags: r, combinatorics

I have an assignment problem where I'm trying to allocate a number of tasks with a known expected cost (runtime in seconds) to X parallel workers, subject to the constraint that each worker receives the same number of tasks (save for remainders), so that the total expected runtime per worker is roughly equal.

I'm using a data frame that defines the tasks to be executed, and for each task I can calculate a pretty accurate expected cost (runtime in seconds). E.g. something like this:

```r
library("tibble")

set.seed(1232)
tasks <- tibble(task = 1:20, cost = runif(20, min = 1, max = 5)^2)
head(tasks)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>    task  cost
#>   <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1 22.5 
#> 2     2 20.0 
#> 3     3 21.3 
#> 4     4  8.13
#> 5     5 18.3 
#> 6     6 19.6
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This is then used with `foreach::foreach(...) %dopar% ...` to execute the tasks in parallel. `foreach()` splits the tasks into roughly equal sized groups with size `nrow(tasks)/X` where `X` is the number of parallel workers (cores).

I'm currently shuffling the task list so that the cost is roughly equal for each worker, but there can still be substantial deviations, i.e. some workers get finished much earlier than others and thus it would have been better if they had had some more costly tasks. E.g.:

```r
# shuffle tasks (in the original application cost is not random initially)
tasks <- tasks[sample(1:nrow(tasks)), ]

# number of workers
X <- 4
tasks$worker <- rep(1:X, each = nrow(tasks)/X)

# expected total cost (runtime in s) per worker
sapply(split(tasks$cost, tasks$worker), sum)
#>        1        2        3        4 
#> 77.25278 35.25026 66.09959 64.05435
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The second worker finishes in half the time as the other workers, so its capacity is wasted and the thing overall takes longer to finish.

What I'd like to do instead is have a way of re-ordering the task data frame so that when `foreach` splits it into X groups the total expected cost per group is more even.

I imagine this is a super-well known kind of problem and I just don't know the right verbiage to google (nor how to do it in R). Thanks for any help.

### (EDIT) Mostly better alternative

For now, a relatively simple alternative that seems to do better than random shuffling. This orders the tasks by cost, assigns the first X tasks to workers 1 to X, then assigns the next chunk of X tasks in reverse order to workers X to 1, etc (this is "alt1" below).

### (EDIT2) Added the RcppAlgos method

By Joseph Wood below.

```r
library("tibble")
library("dplyr")
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library("ggplot2")
library("tidyr")
library("RcppAlgos")

getPartitions <- function(df, nWorkers, tol_ratio = 0.0001) {

  nSections <- nrow(df) / nWorkers
  avg <- sum(df$cost) / nWorkers
  tol <- avg * tol_ratio
  vec <- df$cost
  cond <- TRUE
  part <- list()

  for (i in 1:(nWorkers - 1)) {
      while (cond) {
          vals <- comboGeneral(vec, nSections,
                               constraintFun = "sum",
                               comparisonFun = "==",
                               limitConstraints = avg + (tol / 2),
                               tolerance = tol,
                               upper = 1)

          cond <- nrow(vals) == 0

          if (cond) {
              tol <- tol * 2
          } else {
              v <- match(as.vector(vals), df$cost)
          }
      }

      part[[i]] <- v
      vec <- df$cost[-(do.call(c, part))]
      avg <- sum(vec) / (nWorkers - i)
      tol <- avg * tol_ratio
      cond <- TRUE
  }

  part[[nWorkers]] <- which(!1:nrow(df) %in% do.call(c, part))
  part
}

race <- function() {
  N_TASKS = 100
  X = 4
  tasks <- tibble(task = 1:N_TASKS, cost = runif(N_TASKS, min = 1, max = 10)^2)

  # random shuffle
  tasks$worker <- rep(1:X, each = nrow(tasks)/X)
  rando <- max(sapply(split(tasks$cost, tasks$worker), sum))

  # alternative 1
  tasks <- tasks[order(tasks$cost), ]
  tasks$worker <- rep(c(1:X, X:1), length.out = nrow(tasks))
  alt1 <- max(sapply(split(tasks$cost, tasks$worker), sum))

  # modified version of ivan100sic's answer
  # sort by descending cost, after initial allocation, allocate costly tasks
  # first to workers with lowest total cost so far
  group <- factor(rep(1:(ceiling(nrow(tasks)/4)), each = X))
  tasks <- tasks[order(tasks$cost, decreasing = TRUE), ]
  tasks$worker <- c(1:X, rep(NA, length.out = nrow(tasks) - X))
  task_sets <- split(tasks, group)
  task_sets[[1]]$worker <- 1:X
  for (i in 2:length(task_sets)) {
    # get current total cost by worker
    total <- task_sets %>% 
      bind_rows() %>%
      filter(!is.na(worker)) %>%
      group_by(worker) %>%
      summarize(cost = sum(cost)) %>%
      arrange(cost)
    task_sets[[i]]$worker <- total[["worker"]]
  }
  tasks <- bind_rows(task_sets)
  alt2  <- max(sapply(split(tasks$cost, tasks$worker), sum))

  # RcppAlogs by Joseph Wood below
  setParts <- getPartitions(tasks, X)
  worker   <- rep(1:4, each = N_TASKS/X)
  row_num  <- unsplit(setParts, worker)
  tasks$worker <- worker[order(row_num)]
  algo <- max(sapply(split(tasks$cost, tasks$worker), sum))


  c(ref = sum(tasks$cost) / X, rando = rando, alt1 = alt1, alt2 = alt2, algo = algo)
}

set.seed(24332)
sims <- replicate(1e3, race())
sims <- sims %>%
  t() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  pivot_longer(rando:algo, names_to = "Method")

ggplot(sims, aes(x = value, color = Method)) + 
  geom_density() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, max(sims$value))) +
  labs(x = "Total runtime (s)")
```

[image]

```r
# this shows the estimated runtime relative to average total cost
# per worker (which may be unobtainable)
sims %>%
  group_by(Method) %>%
  summarize(time_relative_to_ref = mean(value - ref)) %>%
  arrange(time_relative_to_ref)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   Method time_relative_to_ref
#>   <chr>                 <dbl>
#> 1 algo                 0.0817
#> 2 alt2                 0.307 
#> 3 alt1                 4.97  
#> 4 rando              154.
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

- "rando": randomly shuffle the task list
- "alt1": sort tasks by cost and alternate assigning to worker 1 to X, X to 1, etc.
- "alt2": based on [ivan100sic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8885293/ivan100sic)'s answer below, after the first allocation to workers 1 to X, allocate based on total cost per worker so far
- "algo": based on [Joseph Woods](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4408538/joseph-wood)'s answer below

Comment: Seems like a variation of the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). It is almost certainly NP-hard. It could be modeled as a 0-1 integer programming problem, and there are doubtless R packages which can solve them.

Comment: It also seems to be linked to the [Job shop scheduling problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling). More generally, there have been many sorts of scheduling problems studied. Since yours is a natural question, I would be surprised if it hasn't been studied, though I have not been able to find a specific link.

Comment: Thanks, those were helpful pointers. I played around with a simple alternative that seems to be better than random shuffling for now, allocating tasks by cost and switching the order of workers they go to successively. in the edit

Comment: It would be interesting to see how this is solved via an 0-1 integer programming problem.

Comment: Any pointers to where I can find more on how to do this as a 0-1 integer programming problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JohnColeman points out, this essentially boils down to partitioning. We are trying to partition the tasks equally such that the sum of the cost doesn't vary wildly.

The algorithm below does just that. The main idea is to successively find a set of tasks whose sum is close to the average. Once we find one, we remove them, and continue selecting.

The work horse of the algorithm below is `comboGeneral` from `RcppAlgos`<sup>*</sup>. This function allows one to find combinations of a vector meeting a constraint. In this case, we are looking for 5 numbers whose sum is close to `sum(tasks$cost) / (number of workers) ~ 60.66425`. Since we are looking for numbers *close* to and not *exact*, we can bound our constraint. That is, we can look for combinations such that the sum is within a given tolerance.

```
library(RcppAlgos)

getPartitions <- function(df, nWorkers, tol_ratio = 0.0001) {

    nSections <- nrow(df) / nWorkers
    avg <- sum(df$cost) / nWorkers
    tol <- avg * tol_ratio
    vec <- df$cost
    cond <- TRUE
    part <- list()

    for (i in 1:(nWorkers - 1)) {
        while (cond) {
            vals <- comboGeneral(vec, nSections,
                                 constraintFun = "sum",
                                 comparisonFun = "==",
                                 limitConstraints = avg + (tol / 2),
                                 tolerance = tol,
                                 upper = 1)

            cond <- nrow(vals) == 0

            if (cond) {
                tol <- tol * 2
            } else {
                v <- match(as.vector(vals), df$cost)
            }
        }

        part[[i]] <- v
        vec <- df$cost[-(do.call(c, part))]
        avg <- sum(vec) / (nWorkers - i)
        tol <- avg * tol_ratio
        cond <- TRUE
    }

    part[[nWorkers]] <- which(!1:nrow(df) %in% do.call(c, part))
    part
}
```

The output for the example given by the OP is as follows:

```
getPartitions(tasks, 4)
[[1]]
[1] 11 13  8 14 10

[[2]]
[1] 12  4 20  2 16

[[3]]
[1] 19  9 18  5  6

[[4]]
[1]  1  3  7 15 17
```

These are the rows from `tasks` that are to be passed to each worker. It runs instantly and returns a pretty even workload. Here are the estimated times for each worker:

```
sapply(getPartitions(tasks, 4), function(x) {
    sum(tasks$cost[x])
})
[1] 60.67292 60.66552 60.80399 60.51455
```

This is pretty good given that the ideal time would be `mean(tasks$cost) * 5 ~= 60.66425`.

Let's see how it performs. Below is a modified script for plotting that takes into account how varied each result is for a given method. We measure this with `sd` (standard deviation). It also returns the ideal solution for reference.

```
library("tibble")
library("dplyr")
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library("ggplot2")
library("tidyr")

race <- function() {
    N_TASKS = 100
    X = 4
    tasks <- tibble(task = 1:N_TASKS, cost = runif(N_TASKS, min = 1, max = 10)^2)
    ideal_soln <- sum(tasks$cost) / X

    # random shuffle
    tasks$worker <- rep(1:X, each = nrow(tasks)/X)
    rando_mx <- max(sapply(split(tasks$cost, tasks$worker), sum))
    rando_sd <- sd(sapply(split(tasks$cost, tasks$worker), sum))

    # alternative 1
    tasks <- tasks[order(tasks$cost), ]
    tasks$worker <- rep(c(1:X, X:1), length.out = nrow(tasks))
    alt1_mx <- max(sapply(split(tasks$cost, tasks$worker), sum))
    alt1_sd <- sd(sapply(split(tasks$cost, tasks$worker), sum))

    # modified version of ivan100sic's answer
    # sort by descending cost, after initial allocation, allocate costly tasks
    # first to workers with lowest total cost so far
    group <- factor(rep(1:(ceiling(nrow(tasks)/4)), each = X))
    tasks <- tasks[order(tasks$cost, decreasing = TRUE), ]
    tasks$worker <- c(1:X, rep(NA, length.out = nrow(tasks) - X))
    task_sets <- split(tasks, group)
    task_sets[[1]]$worker <- 1:X
    for (i in 2:length(task_sets)) {
        # get current total cost by worker
        total <- task_sets %>% 
            bind_rows() %>%
            filter(!is.na(worker)) %>%
            group_by(worker) %>%
            summarize(cost = sum(cost)) %>%
            arrange(cost)
        task_sets[[i]]$worker <- total[["worker"]]
    }
    tasks <- bind_rows(task_sets)
    alt2_mx  <- max(sapply(split(tasks$cost, tasks$worker), sum))
    alt2_sd  <- sd(sapply(split(tasks$cost, tasks$worker), sum))

    ## RcppAlgos solution
    setParts <- getPartitions(tasks, X)
    algos_mx <- max(sapply(setParts, function(x) sum(tasks$cost[x])))
    algos_sd <- sd(sapply(setParts, function(x) sum(tasks$cost[x])))

    c(target_soln = ideal_soln,rando_max = rando_mx, alt1_max = alt1_mx,
      alt2_max = alt2_mx, algos_max = algos_mx, rando_std_dev = rando_sd,
      alt1_std_dev = alt1_sd, alt2_std_dev = alt2_sd, algos_std_dev = algos_sd)
}

set.seed(24332)
system.time(sims <- replicate(1e3, race()))
sims %>%
    t() %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    pivot_longer(rando_std_dev:algos_std_dev, names_to = "Method") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = value, color = Method)) + 
    geom_density() +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100)) +
    labs(x = "Standard Deviation (s)")
Warning message:
Removed 719 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density).
```

[image]

It is hard to tell what is going on because the standard deviation for the `rando` method is so large. If we just look at `alt1`, `alt2`, and the `algos` approach we have:

```
sims %>%
    t() %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    pivot_longer(alt1_std_dev:algos_std_dev, names_to = "Method") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = value, color = Method)) + 
    geom_density() +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 5)) +
    labs(x = "Standard Deviation (s)")
Warning message:
Removed 335 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density)
```

[image]

And now `alt2` and `algos`:

```
sims %>%
    t() %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    pivot_longer(alt2_std_dev:algos_std_dev, names_to = "Method") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = value, color = Method)) + 
    geom_density() +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.7)) +
    labs(x = "Standard Deviation (s)")
```

[image]

As you can see, the `RcppAlgos` solution gives the most balanced load every time.

And finally, here is an illustration that demonstrates how close each method is to the target solution:

```
summary(abs(t(sims)[, "algos_max"] - t(sims)[, "target_soln"]))
    Min.  1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
0.003147 0.057913 0.081986 0.081693 0.106312 0.179099 

summary(abs(t(sims)[, "alt2_max"] - t(sims)[, "target_soln"]))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.01175 0.14321 0.23916 0.30730 0.40949 2.03156

summary(abs(t(sims)[, "alt1_max"] - t(sims)[, "target_soln"]))
  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.4979  2.9815  4.4725  4.9660  6.3220 16.5716 

summary(abs(t(sims)[, "rando_max"] - t(sims)[, "target_soln"]))
 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
13.16   98.14  143.64  154.10  200.41  427.81
```

We see that the `RcppAlgos` solution is around `3-4` times closer on average to the target solution than the second best method (`alt2` in this case).

### Update

For the most part, the `alt2/alt1` methods perform relatively well and are very simple, which is a huge plus. However, there are many cases where they will fail. For example, given ***X*** workers and ***X - 1*** tasks that you know take a substantially longer time than the other tasks, since those methods rely on sorting, they will predictably allocate too much to ***X - 1*** workers. Simply change the following line in the function `race()`:

```
## Original
tasks <- tibble(task = 1:N_TASKS, cost = runif(N_TASKS, min = 1, max = 10)^2)

## Modified
tasks <- tibble(task = 1:N_TASKS, cost = c(runif(X - 1, 15, 25),
                                           runif(N_TASKS - X + 1, min = 1, max = 10))^2)
```

Now rerun and observe:

```
set.seed(24332)
sims <- replicate(1e3, race())
sims <- sims %>%
    t() %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    pivot_longer(rando:algo, names_to = "Method")

ggplot(sims, aes(x = value, color = Method)) + 
    geom_density() +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, max(sims$value))) +
    labs(x = "Total runtime with Large Gap (s)")
```

[image]

```
sims %>%
    group_by(Method) %>%
    summarize(time_relative_to_ref = mean(value - ref)) %>%
    arrange(time_relative_to_ref)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
Method time_relative_to_ref
<chr>                 <dbl>
1 algo                  0.109
2 alt2                150.   
3 alt1                184.   
4 rando               839.
```

Although this is a contrived example, it shows that since the `alt1/alt2` solutions makes assumptions about the underlying data, it will inevitably fail when presented with a more general problem.

<sup>*</sup> Disclosure: I am the author of `RcppAlgos`

Comment: Hi, thanks for pinging me, I had in fact not seen your new answer. I upvoted and added it to the question example. I am reluctant to accept it as the answer though because the improvement over the much simpler alt2 method above seems to be marginal. Any idea under what circumstances your solution would work substantially better than alt2 or be preferable for some other reason?

Comment: @andybega, your comment is spot on. I agree that the `alt2` or even the `alt1` methods are probably better solutions to your problem simply because of their simplicity and decent accuracy. When I posted originally, the `alt2` method had not been presented. At that time I was using version `2.3.4` of `RcppAlgos` and found that when applied to the simulated data, the execution time was terrible. I was in the process of updating the algorithm for finding combinations that summed close to a target value, and this question really pushed me to complete that work... continuing

Comment: @andybega, I was actually going to mention that this question was a huge inspiration for the finished work of version `2.3.6`. For the past 2 months I have been using this very example for much of my testing. I only undeleted the post because I believe this can be extended to more cases and hopefully it will help somebody. E.g. Here is a similar question that I believe the `alt2` and `alt1` method will not work but the `RcppAlgos` solution does well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59682706/4408538. Thanks for your work on this problem and thanks for the great question (I upvoted 2 months ago).

Comment: @andybega, I believe I have found a decent example. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

The following heuristic might give you good results:

Sort all the tasks by cost in **descending order**. For each task, assign it to the worker which has the minimum total assigned cost so far.

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer.

Comment: Yes, but I don't yet have the reputation to comment, and I wanted to help.

Comment: ok... +1 to get you more reputation. It would be interesting to see if this approach is better than the alternative approach in the edited question...

Comment: hello, thanks for your comment/answer :) I added it to the example after the edit, as "alt2". BTW, I don't have control over how many total tasks each worker gets, they all end up with an equal number of tasks. I checked one iteration manually and it is the case that the assignment it has differs from that in "alt1", but overall the improvement seems to only be slight. I'm gonna try it with my actual application too, that one has a very heavy right tail in the cost distribution, maybe that makes a difference.