# Pool items in database until minimum sample size reached and find all permutations in R

Tags: r, permutation

This is an example.

```
df <- data.frame(item=letters[1:5], n=c(3,2,2,1,1))
df
  item n
1    a 3
2    b 2
3    c 2
4    d 1
5    e 1
```

Item needs to be grouped so that the group has a sample size of at least 4.

This would be the solution if you follow the sorting of df.

```
  item n cluster
1    a 3       1
2    b 2       1
3    c 2       2
4    d 1       2
5    e 1       2
```

How to get all possible unique solutions?

Further, the code should also not allow any clusters to have a sample size less than 4.

Comment: you might want to check out the `RcppAlgos` package. How many unique items do you have in your actual dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below, we have a brute force approach using the package `partitions`. The idea is that we find every partition of the rows of `df`. We then sum each group and check to see that the requirement has been met.

```
df <- data.frame(item=letters[1:5], n=c(3,2,2,1,1))

minSize <- 4

funGetClusters <- function(df, minSize) {
    allParts <- partitions::listParts(nrow(df))

    goodInd <- which(sapply(allParts, function(p) {
        all(sapply(p, function(x) sum(df$n[x])) >= minSize)
    }))

    allParts[goodInd]
}

clusterBreakdown <- funGetClusters(df, minSize)

allDfs <- lapply(clusterBreakdown, function(p) {
    copyDf <- df
    copyDf$cluster <- 1L
    clustInd <- 2L

    for (i in p[-1]) {
        copyDf$cluster[i] <- clustInd
    }

    copyDf
})
```

Here is the output:

```
allDfs
[[1]]
  item n cluster
1    a 3       1
2    b 2       1
3    c 2       1
4    d 1       1
5    e 1       1

[[2]]
  item n cluster
1    a 3       1
2    b 2       2
3    c 2       2
4    d 1       1
5    e 1       1

[[3]]
  item n cluster
1    a 3       2
2    b 2       1
3    c 2       1
4    d 1       2
5    e 1       1

[[4]]
  item n cluster
1    a 3       2
2    b 2       1
3    c 2       1
4    d 1       1
5    e 1       2

[[5]]
  item n cluster
1    a 3       2
2    b 2       1
3    c 2       2
4    d 1       1
5    e 1       1

[[6]]
  item n cluster
1    a 3       2
2    b 2       2
3    c 2       1
4    d 1       1
5    e 1       1
```

It should be noted, that there is a combinatorial explosion as the number of rows increases. For example, just with 10 rows we would have to test `115975` different partitions.

As @chinsoon comments, `RcppAlgos` could be a good choice for an acceptable solution for larger cases. Disclaimer, I am the author. I have answered similar questions with much larger inputs and have had good success.

- [Allocating tasks to parallel workers so that expected cost is roughly equal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58975589/4408538)
- [Split a set into n unequal subsets with the key deciding factor being that the elements in the subset aggregate and equal a predetermined amount?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59682706/4408538)

  - @AllanCameron also has a great answer and nice methodology to attacking this problem. You should give that a read as well.

Lastly, the following vignette by Robin K. S. Hankin (author of the `partitions` package) and Luke J. West is not only a great read, but very applicable to problems like the one presented here.

- [Set Partitions in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partitions/vignettes/setpartitions.pdf)